# How to pass data from a button to a modal laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

i cant pass data from the product selected, i used jquery to pass data but nothing show when the modal is open

[image]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="product" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar producto</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> 
  
 
    <form method="PUT" action="productos">
    @csrf     
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label >description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" required>
    </div>    
  </form>


  <script>
  $('#product').on('show', function(e) {
    var link     = e.relatedTarget(),
        modal    = $(this),
        name = link.data("name"),
        description    = link.data("description");

    modal.find("#name").val(name);
    modal.find("#description").val(description);
});
  </script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

@endsection
```

this is how it looks when i press the edit button

[image]

how can i fix this? or why my jquery is not working i try using another options like  in the data-target put this `data-target="#product-model-{{ $product }}` but doesnt work.

Comment: Hi, you have error inside your jquery code after fixing them check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fvLy60dc/) working code.